# Simple HTML as blog

Tags: html

I've fooled with many blogging platforms, and develop in Ruby right now...I'm tired of dealing with databases and upgrading applications--so for my personal blog, I'd like to stick with pure html.

**Is this a bad idea?**

The only dilemma is if I have a lot of entries...

If you were to do something like this (given that you answered 'no' to the previous question), how would you go about formatting it and how would you deal with many entries?

Comment: Tried [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at static blogging platforms like [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll)?

See minitech's answer, static HTML is good for all the reasons he lists, and also:

- improved performance! Servers serve static files REALLY fast, and to well under load
- reliability. There's very little to break besides your Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bad idea at all. Reasons to use it:

- No need to install a server-side language or anything, or worry about compatibility
- Reduces the load on your server
- No databases to set up, nothing to debug, just generally lightweight.

Reasons you may not want to:

- Duplicated code. If you want to change something about your entire site, it may be difficult to change it in all pages.

But go for it, it's simple and effective. You can name things whatever you want, and backup is as easy as just copying all the files. It works on any kind of server, too.

Answer (score 1):

Without being *truly* static, I can say that PHP certainly makes a *mostly* static page highly convenient:

```
<?php include('/path/to/header.inc'); ?>
<h1>Not much boilerplate</h1>
<p>Considering that only two lines are needed</p>
<?php include('/path/to/footer.inc'); ?>
```

A number of alternatives can be used. I use one internally that takes advantage of the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable and parses markdown, with `16` lines of PHP code and [PHPMarkdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

---

There's nothing particularly wrong with using static HTML for a website, so long as you understand that any site-wide changes will be tedious and slow compared to a dynamic system.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @KevinBrown, the question I answered was "Is this a bad idea?", and my answer was "There's nothing particularly wrong with using static HTML for a website".

Comment: There's another question if you read the whole post.

Comment: @KevinBrown, I read the whole post, I answered your question in **bold**. Your auxiliary question is partially answered in my first suggestion, which is to use a very small amount of dynamic server-side code to manage the repetitious parts of your website.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [jeckyl](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), hyde, octopress and all other static pages generators.

Generally it's not a bad idea and a lot of people are doing this generating their blogs as static pages and adding js commenting via [disqus](http://disqus.com).

Those solutions allows you to pretty quicly change layout, add widgets with latest post etc.